# What is the purpose of the function (toEnum . fromEnum) in Haskell code?

Tags: haskell

I saw the function `toEnum . fromEnum` being used on `Char`s in [`HaskellNet.Network.Auth`](https://github.com/jtdaugherty/HaskellNet/blob/master/src/Network/HaskellNet/Auth.hs#L29).

```
b64Encode :: String -> String
b64Encode = map (toEnum.fromEnum) . B64.encode . map (toEnum.fromEnum)

b64Decode :: String -> String
b64Decode = map (toEnum.fromEnum) . B64.decode . map (toEnum.fromEnum)
```

At first glance this function should be identical to `id`, right? Why is it here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *can* be equivalent to `id`, but only in certain situations. Since `fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int` can convert *any* `Enum` to an `Int`, and `toEnum :: Enum a => Int -> a` can convert an `Int` to *any* `Enum`, it follows that `toEnum . fromEnum` is a general method of converting from *any* enum to *any* enum — that is, `(toEnum . fromEnum) :: (Enum a, Enum b) => a -> b`. As you have observed, this should indeed identical to `id` (if the `Enum` instance has been implemented properly, that is), but only when you select `a` and `b` as being the same type; otherwise, it converts from one `Enum` instance to a different `Enum` instance.

As for why it is used in that particular place: I really have no idea. `B64.decode` and `B64.encode` appear to both be `String -> String`, and `b64Decode` and `b64Encode` are *also* `String -> String`, so `toEnum . fromEnum` converts from `Char` to `Char` — so in this case it should be identical to `id`. In other words, `toEnum . fromEnum` does nothing here and probably should be removed (although I won’t rule out the possibility that the `Enum` instance for `Char` is implemented in such a way that this isn’t `id`).

**EDIT:** @K.A.Buhr has found an explanation for this in the Git history of the project. It appears that `encode` and `decode` used to have signatures involving `ByteString`, so `toEnum` and `fromEnum` were used to convert between lists of `Word8` (for `ByteString`) and lists of `Char` (for `String`). At some point `encode` and `decode` were switched to use `String` rather than `ByteString`, but no-one removed the `toEnum` and `fromEnum`.

Comment: Looking through the Git history of the project, it looks like `B64` used to refer to module `Codec.Binary.Base64` where `encode` and `decode` work on `ByteString`, so these functions were being used to convert between `ByteString` and `String`.  At some point, someone switched `B64` to module `Codec.Binary.Base64.String`, but didn't bother to update the definitions to, say, `b64Encode = B64.encode` and `b64Decode = B64.decode`.

Comment: Thanks @K.A.Buhr! I did wonder whether something like that had happened. Can I edit that into my answer?

Comment: Sure, please do.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Thanks! Done.